# Nome do aplicativo não aparece no emulador igual aparece quando estou mexendo no código

Tags: android, xml

O nome da aplicação que to fazendo no  android studio não aparece na tela do emulador.

Está aparecendo o ícone instalado e o nome,mas não aparece na tela ou no programinha.

Teria que entrar na pasta `res` e em `string` ou no `manisfesto` para mudar alguma coisa?

Comment: posta um print indicando onde não está aparecendo o nome e o código do seu manifest pra gente, por favor

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Sua pergunta noa ficou muito clara, mas se deseja mudar o nome da aplicação em si, será no seu `AndroidManifest.xml` na tag `application`, onde `android:label` irá definir o nome da aplicação (por padrão vc irá consumir de alguma string):

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icone_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icone_logo_rounded"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </application>
```

Veja aqui todos os parâmetros da tag application: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element?hl=pt-br

Caso deseje alterar o titulo da activity em si, na `ActionBar`, será a mesma lógica, mas será colocado dentro de cada `activity` declarada:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".Chat.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/titulo_activity_chat"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TemaPrincipal" />
```

Veja aqui todos os parâmetros da tag activity: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=pt-br

Ah, e caso esteja se referindo se a toolbar está ou não aparecendo, verifique no seu `styles` se o seu theme não está herdando de algum `temaNoActionBar`.
Caso esteja `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`, com esse theme não terá a barra de titulos.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Jefferson,

No seu AndroidManifest.xml, você deve deixar setado a label da atividade, por exemplo:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/titulo_da_tela" >
</activity>
```

Isso vai fazer com que essa label aparece na ActionBar.

Abraços.