# Alterar o nome do Aplicativo no Xamarin Forms - Problema

Tags: xamarin-forms

Estou tentando mudar o nome do meu aplicativo criado no Xamarin Forms, mas não consigo. Já achei esses dois links que explicam como fazer isso:

[Nome do aplicativo não aparece no emulador igual aparece quando estou mexendo no código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135952/nome-do-aplicativo-n%C3%A3o-aparece-no-emulador-igual-aparece-quando-estou-mexendo-no)

[É possível editar o nome de um projeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271822/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-editar-o-nome-de-um-projeto)

Eu sei que tem que editar o AndroidManifest o campo android:label="", porem quando eu faço isso e coloco meu aplicativo para rodar eu fico observando esse campo e antes de "subir" a aplicação o nome volta a ser o que era. Por exemplo, supondo que o nome que esta lá é "Aplicacao" eu vou e troco para "MeuApp" coloco para rodar, logo antes de iniciar a aplicação o campo se altera novamente para "Aplicacao". Alguem sabe como resolver isso? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aletere a linha na sua MainActitivity.cs

```
     [Activity(Label = "Nome", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/splashscreen", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
....
```

}

`[Activity(Label = "Nome" ...` substitua o "Nome" para o que vai usar na sua aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, problema resolvido.